# I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make an Tic Tac Toe game in discord.js, but I am pretty new to javascript in general so I am probably making this poorly but, I hope it's repairable.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();
let ano = []
let ID = []
let check = []
let ček = []
let hráč = []
let gejmr = []

bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am online and ready for some action!")
check.push("ne")
ček.push("ne")

})


bot.on("message", message =>{
  if(message.content.startsWith("!ttt")){
    if(!ček.includes("ne")){return}
    ček.splice(0)
    hráč.push(message.author.username)
    let filter = f => f.author.id === message.author.id
    let filter1 = m => m.mentions.users.first() === message.mentions.users.first()
message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} **VS** ... \n
⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜\n
načítám reakce...`).then(zpráva =>{
zpráva.react("↖️"), zpráva.react("⬆️"), zpráva.react("↗️"), zpráva.react("⬅️"), zpráva.react(""), zpráva.react("➡️"), zpráva.react("↙️"), zpráva.react("⬇️"), zpráva.react("↘️")
setTimeout(() => {
  zpráva.edit(`${message.author.username} **VS** ...: \n
:white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square:
:white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square:
:white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square:`)
check.splice(0)

}, 8180);
ano.push(message.author.id)
message.channel.send(ano)
ID.push(zpráva.id)

})



  bot.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
    if(check.includes("ne")){return}
    if(ID.includes(reaction.message.id)){
      if(reaction.emoji.name === ""||reaction.emoji.name === "↖️"||reaction.emoji.name === "⬆️"||reaction.emoji.name === "↗️"||reaction.emoji.name === "⬅️"||reaction.emoji.name === "➡️"||reaction.emoji.name === "↙️"||reaction.emoji.name === "⬇️"||reaction.emoji.name === "↘️"){
    let args = reaction.message.content.substring(`${user.username} **VS** ...:`.length).split(" ")
        if(hráč.includes(user.username)){
          let ano = ":regional_indicator_x:"
          if(reaction.emoji.name === "↖️"){if(args[1] === ":white_large_square:"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${ano} ${args[2]} ${args[3]}
${args[4]} ${args[5]} ${args[6]}
${args[7]} ${args[8]} ${args[9]}`).then(hezů =>{console.log(hezů.content)})} else {return}

          } else if(reaction.emoji.name === "⬆️"){if(args[2] === ":white_large_square:"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[1]} ${ano} ${args[3]}
${args[4]} ${args[5]} ${args[6]}
${args[7]} ${args[8]} ${args[9]}`).then(hezů =>{console.log(hezů.content)})} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "↗️"){if(args[3] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]}  
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[9]} ${args[10]} ${args[11]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "⬅️"){if(args[5] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
 ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === ""){if(args[6] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]}  ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "➡️"){if(args[7] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} 
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "↙️"){if(args[9] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
 ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "⬇️"){if(args[10] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]}  ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "↘️"){if(args[11] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} `)} else {return}
}
        } else


        if(gejmr.includes(user.username)){
          if(reaction.emoji.name === "↖️"){if(args[0] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
️ ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}

          } else if(reaction.emoji.name === "⬆️"){if(args[1] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ️ ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "↗️"){if(args[2] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ️ 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "⬅️"){if(args[3] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
️ ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === ""){if(args[4] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ️ ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "➡️"){if(args[5] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ️
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "↙️"){if(args[6] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
️ ${args[7]} ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "⬇️"){if(args[7] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ️ ${args[8]}`)} else {return}
} else if(reaction.emoji.name === "↘️"){if(args[8] === "⬜"){reaction.message.edit(`${user.username} **VS** ... \n
${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]} 
${args[3]} ${args[4]} ${args[5]}
${args[6]} ${args[7]} ️`)} else {return}
}
        }



      } else {
    reaction.remove()}
    } else return
  })
```

Aaaand, the reason why I have somewhere ":white_large_square:" and somewhere "⬜" is because I was testing the problem with args, problem I noticed is that "⬜" is read like 2 characters with spaces cause of being an emoji.
*The reason why I have the Middle finger emoji is because I could not find good emoji that will be as middle*

The problem that I have is that it makes it in weird order. [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kNCu.jpg)

Comment: What's the error? Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I edited it, the problem is that it makes it in a weird order. Like
x o
x 
o o 
o x o x